# Does Jax's Grandmaster's Might passive trigger Deathfire Touch?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does the third strike on Jax's Grandmaster's Might passive trigger the Deathfire Touch keystone?

Comment: good question. I´ll test this later today and post results tomorrow if noone else does. I would suggest you use the stacking physical dmg on-hit though.

Comment: I know that it does not work on Diana's, probably because you don't actually cast anything. But the keystone does trigger on Brand's passive...

Comment: @Eumel thats what i was using, i just wanted to know in case. New hybrid Jax is awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Jax's Grandmaster's Might passive does trigger Deathfire Touch.**
I have not tested this myself (I might later and edit to confirm), but the wiki provides information as to why this is so.

On the [Deathfire Touch](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Deathfire_Touch_(Season_2016_Mastery)) page:

> - Deathfire Touch is a spell effect and will only be applied to instances of ability damage.

Now we know Deathfire Touch is a spell effect, but does Grandmaster's Might passive count as ability damage? Yes.
On the [spell effect](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Spell_effect#On-Hit_Effects) page:

> The following "on-hit effects" are incorrectly, although possibly intentionally classified as abilities and will trigger spell effects. The triggering attack can still trigger on-hit effects.
>   [...]
>
> - Jax's Empower
>
>   - Grandmaster's Might (passive)

And on the Jax page under [Grandmaster's Might](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Jax#Grandmaster.27s_Might) (click show ability details):

> Grandmaster's Might is a self-buff ability that passively grants Jax an on-hit effect on all his basic attacks.
>
> - Applies spell effects as a single target ability.
>
>   - Spell vamp is fully applied.
>   - Will of the Ancients will heal you for 15% of the raw damage dealt.
>   - Rylai's Crystal Scepter will apply a 40% slow for 1.5 seconds.

Grandmaster's Might passive grants an on-hit effect of extra damage on every third basic attack in 2.5 seconds. Since this on-hit effect is classed as ability damage, it will apply spell effects and therefore Deathfire Touch.

I think it is safe to assume that, as @Gnarly 404 stated in the comments for @Eumel's answer, "[...] everything that triggers a Luden's Echo or Liandry's will also trigger Deathfire Touch." A quick look at some other abilities listed on the spell effect wiki page, such as Gragas's [Drunken Rage](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Gragas#Drunken_Rage) and Kassadin's [Nether Blade](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kassadin#Nether_Blade), confirms that this is probably the case. I did not check all of them, so feel free to prove me wrong.

Comment: if you check my answer below, i did the testing and it does apply

Comment: @Eumel yes I saw your answer, I just wanted to add some information to back up the result.

Comment: my comment was aimed at you editid your post to state that testing was done and information was right, forgot that i could edit as well^^

Comment: I did not decide to edit in that you tested it and works, as I said I would edit if I tested it myself. Others can see your comments here adding that it has been tested by you and works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess here (99% sure) based on the fact that Diana´s passive and EZ´s Q doesn't trigger it.

Both those spells are actually not coded as a spell but as a special kind of autoattack particle (source somewhere on patchnotes or the riot forum) thus they do not proc Deathfire or Ludens Echo. Brand's passive, on the other hand, is a spell like any other DOT.

I did the testing just now Jax´s ultimate actually does proc Deathfire Touch so I take back what I said before.

There you have your answer though.

Comment: so i would assume that the same is true of Gangplank parley then? how about something like nasus siphoning strike?

Comment: I think that everything that triggers a Luden's Echo or Liandry's will also trigger Deathfire Touch.

Answer (score -2):

Well, if it doesn't work on Diana, it's not going to work on Jax either. Mainly because is a passive spell rather than an active spell.

Comment: Passive spells can still proc spell hit effects, the big one being Brand's burn.